# Generics more restricted type for constructor

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I will have multiple constructors, other can use `T`, but one constructor has to use `Comparable`

I tried to use

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>>TestT() // does not help
```

the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestT<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> arr;
    
    public TestT() {
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    void push(T e){
        arr.add(e);
    }
}
```

How to make it so TestT constructor will allow only Comparable? Assuming I have other constructors which do not require Comparable

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking. How does a constructor "use" generics if they're not used for parameters? `TestT<T>` defines a type on the class, so how and why would the constructor be adding different constraints like `Comparable<T>` etc.? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: let's say someone will call TestT() => this one should be Comparable.
but if someone will call TestT(Comparator<T> c), then the constructor should not require T to be Comparable, as a dev sends specific Comparator.
In the end TestT() call needs to be Comparable, while TestT(Comparator<T> c) - not

Comment: This doesn't work as the restriction would need to be at the type level. Let's assume you have a variable of type `TestT<Whatever>`. How do you know whether `Whatever` needs to implement `Comparable<Whatever>` or not? Remember, you just have that type and no info on the constructor - much like the compiler can't rely on having that information. - To cut it short: this can't be implemented the way you want.

Comment: Another hint: `TreeSet` is a standard class that has similar requirements but even that doesn't use generics to enforce `Comparable<T>` at compile time - instead it relies on runtime checks when trying to add elements, i.e. when there is no `Comparator` it _assumes_ that `T extends Comparable<T>` and attempts a cast. If what you're trying to do was possible, don't you think the Java devs themselves would use it?

Comment: One solution is to make your constructors private, and use factory methods to create instances. These can each have their own generic constraints as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the below code answers to your requirements:

```
class TestT<T> {
    private List<T> arr;
    
    // Constructor that receives Comparable
    protected <X extends Comparable<? super X>> TestT(X comparableIn1, X comparableIn2) {
        /* Locate here your logic that transforms the input Comparable to List<T> */
        // some foolish example implementation
        if (comparableIn1.compareTo(comparableIn2) > 0) {
            arr = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        else {
            arr = new LinkedList<>();
        }
    }
    
    // Another Constructor that receives a Collection of Comparable
    protected <X extends Comparable<? super X>> TestT(Collection<X> comparableCollection) {
        /* Locate here your logic that transforms the input Comparable Set to List<T> */
    }

    // Another Constructor that receives something else
    protected TestT(List<T> listOfАrbitraries) {
        arr = listOfАrbitraries;
    }

    void push(T e){
        arr.add(e);
    }
}

// Create different instances by the above Constructor receiving Comparable
TestT<Integer> arrayListOfIntegers = new TestT<>("1","0");
TestT<Object> linkedListOfObjects = new TestT<>("1","2");
```

Frankly, the notation `<X extends Comparable<? super X>>` can be simplified to just `<X extends Comparable<X>>`. In this case your Constructor argument's type will need to implement `compareTo(X o)` method, while in a manner I wrote above, the Comparable Interface can be also implemented by a method `compareTo(<? super X> o)` and the method's definition can be also in one of X's super types.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make much sense since all constructor have the same name. Try using `static` methods instead:

```
public class TestT<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> arr;

    public static <X extends Comparable<X>> TestT<X> comparable() {
        return new TestT<>();
    }

    private TestT() {
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    void push(T e){
        arr.add(e);
    }
}
```